# How to pass props to a non rendered function in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a very simple React app that shows total days and how many of these were missed:

```
export const DayCount = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h4>Total days: { props.total }</h4>
    <h4>Missed days: { props.missed } </h4>
  </div>
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DayCount total={10} missed={1} />
    )
  }
}
```

I want to make a calculator that shows the % of days which were attended. However it seems the props cannt be passed in the same way to my PercentageFunc function?

```
export const PercentageFunc = (props) => {
  return (props.total - props.missed) / props.total;
};


export const DayCount = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h4>Total days: { props.total }</h4>
    <h4>Missed days: { props.missed } </h4>
    <h1>% attended: { PercentageFunc() }</h1>
  </div>
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DayCount total={10} missed={1} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: seems like you forgot to pass the "props" to *PercentageFunc()*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are calling `PercentageFunc`, but not passing it the prop data here

```
<h1>% attended: { PercentageFunc() }</h1>
```

While that function is expecting data, as per the method signature you've defined:

```
export const PercentageFunc = (props) => {
  return (props.total - props.missed) / props.total;
};
```

You'll need to pass `props` to `PercentageFunc` when it is called (`PercentageFunc(props)`)

It's important to remember that React components are "just" functions, and props is "just" the name of a parameter to that function.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass the "props" in your component.
It must be:

```
<PercentageFunc total={props.total} missed={props.missed} />
```